# Control Panel or admin dashboard not found

Tags: error, admin, 404

I have installed craftcms 3 on my localhost. It got installed and the following screen appeared:
[image: screen which appears]

If I click on Control Panel I see the following screen

[image: error 404 not found]

Comment: I added minimum steps to make a virtual host and this will surely solve your issue.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: yes and thanks for the guidance

Comment: I am getting same error but i did this code with in 000-default.conf but i get same error, what is file permission 777 of web,config,modules,composer.lock,comsoper.json my virtual host -> http://mycraftserver.test/admin/login
<VirtualHost *:80> ServerName craftcms.local ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost DocumentRoot /var/www/html/craft/web/ ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined <Directory /var/www/html> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews AllowOverride ALL Require all granted </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: I am having the same issue, I tried the host file craftcms.local.conf, but it's not working for me. It worth to say that I installed CraftCMS by downloading the zip from the git releases and `./craft install` because I need the exact version `4.4.14`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user suggested, Just create a **virtual host** by following the below mentioned steps.

Complete Article : [Virtual Host](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

1. sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/craftcms.local.conf
2. sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/craftcms.local.conf
3. Paste the below lines in above file (`craftcms.local.conf`)

   ```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerName craftcms.local
           ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
           DocumentRoot /var/www/html/craftcms/web/
           ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
           CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

           <Directory /var/www/html>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride ALL
                    Require all granted
           </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>

   # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
   ```
4. sudo a2ensite craftcms.local.conf
5. sudo service apache2 restart
6. sudo nano /etc/hosts

   add a new hosts at the end of this file like
   `127.0.0.1   craftcms.local`
7. Open your browser and hit `craftcms.local` frontend and `craftcms.local/admin` for admin

Comment: thanks for the guidance, this worked perfectly.

Comment: @falcon , you can mark the answer as accepted or even you can share your's as answer.

Comment: @saurabh, I again followed the same steps on Ubuntu 19.10 but this time the control panel url [http://craftcms.local/admin] shows the same 404 Not Found error. What to do now?

Comment: craftcms.local shows the Welcome Page but when you click on control panel [craftcms.local/admin] it shows 404 error not found :(

Comment: @falcon  check your .env at root of the project and update/add `DEFAULT_SITE_URL="craftcms.local"`

Comment: it's already there in the .env file.

Comment: @falcon did you solve your problem ?

Comment: Maybe this will help someone else, but I also needed to manually enable the Apache Rewrite module. `sudo a2enmod rewrite && sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: @blendenzo  - Thanks for this comment. That's what fixed this issue for me too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the web server to host from the /web directory. At present it looks like you are serving a folder that contains the Craft folder.